# Should I ask my potential supervisor for a PhD admission result?

Tags: phd, graduate-admissions, united-states

I have been admitted to a PhD program in the USA. However, it isn't my first choice. I am waiting for the results of other programs I am more interested in. Should I ask my potential supervisors (I contacted potential supervisors at those programs; they said they would advocate my application) at the program about my result? If yes, how should I ask? Should I imply that I need to respond to another program, but your program is my first choice, so I would like to get the result at your earliest possibility?

Comment: Almost all PhD programs in the USA allow you until April 15 to respond to their offers of admission and funding.  Do you actually need to respond to the other program?  It's awfully early in the admissions cycle right now.

Comment: Hi @AlexanderWoo, I don't need to respond formally. However, I need to verbally respond to my potential supervisor at a university because he needs to allocate the assistantship.

Comment: @Hung what did you decide do to if anything? I am stuck in your exact position right now.

Comment: @SPSharan I decided to email the admission secretary of one program but haven't had a reply yet. For another uni, I emailed my potential supervisor directly and got the reply.